# Paste issue with IE9 using Handsontable

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer-9, handsontable

I don't think handsontable is officially supported for IE9 but i'm hoping someone might be able to help me come up with a fix for this formatting issue that only shows in IE9

Basically if you look at this example (http://jsfiddle.net/warpech/hU6Kz/) in IE9 and Chrome, and then paste some cells from Excel into the table, you lose the cell borders

```
$("#exampleGrid").handsontable({
    data: myData,
    startRows: 5,
    startCols: 5,
    minSpareCols: 1,
    //always keep at least 1 spare row at the right
    minSpareRows: 1,
    //always keep at least 1 spare row at the bottom,
    rowHeaders: true,
    colHeaders: true,
    contextMenu: true
});
```

IE9:

[image]
Chrome:

[image]

Unfortunately, I have to use IE9 for this so any help would be appreciated (or if it's not possible, recommendations for a similar library?)

Thanks in advance

Comment: The copy-paste plugin handsontable uses may not be suitable for IE9. Maybe look around for a copy-paste library which does work well in IE and implement the feature in your table

Comment: Thanks @ZekeDroid - I've decided not to use handsontable now